# Criar tabela temporária com a estrutura de outra tabela mantendo as restrições de chave primaria

Tags: postgresql, table, create

Sou leigo ainda no postgresql e gostaria da ajuda de alguém.

Criei um tabela temporária (como é citado no manual do postgresql):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS s_agendatemp (like s_agendamento INCLUDING INDEXES)
```

A tabela de origem s_agendamento tem como chave primária o campo ID. Essa tabela de origem já está populada (por exemplo: nela consta os ID's: 5,7,9,10,15 cadastrados), então pela lógica, se eu inserisse outro registro, o próximo ID seria o 16. Pelo manual do postgresql as restrições de índices, PRIMARY KEY , UNIQUE e EXCLUDE na tabela original serão criadas na nova tabela somente se INCLUDING INDEXES for especificado.

Eu estou especificando isso no comando create table, porém quando insiro um novo registro na tabela temporária ele ignora as restrições de chave primária.

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Pela sua descrição creio que o problema esteja na `sequence` associada à primary key da tabela. Não creio que o comportamento da sequence da nova tabela seja o que você espera. Verifique as sequences de cada uma das tabelas e compare-as.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou verificar sua sugestão.